# Why does this regex not evaluate to true in perl?

Tags: regex, perl

I'm wrapping my first content string in single quotes to simplify what I'm asking.  Its not wrapped in my code.

```
'{
#    "ERROR" : [
#       "generic error message"
#    ]
# }' =~ {
```

It seems like this should be true because I'm just checking the first expression for a open bracket but its evaluating to false.

Comment: Huh? What? That code is not complete. Did you mean the regex `/{/` (which works)?

Comment: don't now perl at all, but maybe escape it because it's a metacharacter? `\{`

Comment: @amon do you need to wrap your regex when evaluating with the =~ operator in perl?

Comment: What do you mean by “wrapping”? It is just `$string =~ /regex/` or `$string =~ m<funky delims>` or `$string =~ $something_representing_a_regex`.

Comment: @amon well, when I evaluate in a language like php i need to wrap my regex in delimiters, the forward slashes for example in /regex/. based on how I'm seeing the =~ used in the code I'm looking at I didn't think you needed the delimiters in perl when using =~

Comment: In PHP's `preg_*` functions, the regex is a normal string (complete with normal quotes). In Perl, regexes can be literals. These usually look like `"foo" =~ /o/`. When slashes are inconvenient, you can pick your own delimiter like `$url =~ m{http://}`. To save a compiled regex to a variable, use `qr//` quotes: `my $http_regex = qr~http://~`.

Comment: @amon actually thats really helpful.  I think I have the hang of it now.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @amon: make your last comment an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In languages like PHP, a regex is just an ordinary string, complete with quotes: `"/regex/"`. Perl, on the other hand, has regex literals. These are directly embedded into the code, but still need delimiters.

In general, this looks like:

```
$string =~ /regex/
```

The slashes are the default delimiter. if slashes are an inconvenient delimiter, you can choose any other<sup>(1)</sup>—just prefix the regex with `m` (for match). These matches are equivalent:

```
$url =~ /http:\/\///;
$url =~ m/http:\/\///;
$url =~ m{http://};
```

If you want to store a precompiled regex in a variable,  you can use `qr//` quotes. Prefer these to plain strings, because `qr//` regexes follow the same quoting rules as regexes (no double escapes):

```
my $url_regex = qr~http://~;
$url =~ $url_regex;
```

The `=~` bind operator tries its best to interpret the right hand argument as a regex, so you could even use strings, in a php-like fashion:

```
"123\nab12" =~ "\\d\n\\w+"; # double escaping sucks, still matches
```

but this is inferior to `/\d\n\w+/`.

Therefore, is not possible to skip any delimiter whatsoever:

```
# "=~" has higher precedence than "+".
# Establishing precedence is the *sole* task of the parens here
"112" =~ (1+2); # fails
"3"   =~ (1+2); # matches
"112" =~ /1+2/; # matches
```

---

1. Don't use question marks as regex delimiters, these match only once.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
'your string' =~ /\{/
```

Your syntax is not valid as shown because `{` is not a regular expression. To fix that issue, I wrapped it in the default regular expression characters to get `/{/`, and then escaped `{` (resulting in `/\{/`) because it's a metacharacter of regular expression syntax. (For the regex `x{a,b}` means that `x` should be repeated at least `a` and at most `b` times.)

Comment: Actually, that can't be the issue: perl is smart enough to figure out that the `{` in `/{/` isn't a metacharacter.

Comment: You're right. However, in the above code, simply the character `{` is used, not a regex (e.g., `/\{/`). When I corrected the syntax I escaped the `{`, which I'm explaining, but you're right that it's not clear. I'll clarify my answer.